# Elixir GenStage Batching Events

Tags: elixir

Given a producer that returns:

```
events = [1,2,3]
{:noreply, events, state}
```

Is each list item an event, or is the list itself the event?

If case is the former: consumers will automatically receive the number of events each consumer asks for (value is configured and process is handled by genserver internals)

Or if latter: It's up to the producer to send the correct number of events.

I believe the docs and examples point to the first case.

Answer (score -1):

1. There are items in the list being the events. [`GenStage.handle_demand/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html#c:handle_demand/2) is explicitly typed to return a list as a second parameter; if it were the event itself, anything would be supported as a return value.
2. There are four very clear examples in [`gen_stage/examples`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/blob/master/examples) that could basically answer all questions like that: reading code does always better clarify intent that the documentation of any quality, even despite Elixir documentation is nearly brilliant.

   2.1. The most contrived example would be just [dispatching events](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/blob/master/examples/gen_event.exs#L49). It is using `state` to store *both* queue of undispatched yet events *and* the number of events requested. Please note, that it might block on empty `queue`.

   2.2. The [`rate_limiter` example’s code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/blob/master/examples/rate_limiter.exs#L14) provides a plain answer to your question regarding who is responsible for counting a number of events.